# Load HTML page inside flex popup window

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have created a popup window in a flex website and I wanted to load a HTML page inside that popup. I tried many ways to do it but that way unsuccessful. Can someone recommend me a approach to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

if by loading an html page you mean load and show html content, then you will need Adobe AIR. Flash and Flex in the browser can't render html content.

You can load the html source and parse the text off it... to show it as a text box. But I guess that's not what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,
http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm

you can download source from here
http://www.deitte.com/IFrameDemo3/srcview/index.html